# Group and collapse rows in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to collapse data, and I don't understand how to show column for grouping by which is need to collapse data

```
 var rangeStaff = staffInWork.getRange(2,1,LASTROWSTAFFINWORK-1,LASTCOLUMNSTAFFINWORK);
     rangeStaff.shiftRowGroupDepth(1);  
 var groupStaff = staffInWork.getRowGroupAt( ? 'I do not know what settings insert here '?);
     groupStaff.collapse();
```

- [sheet before row grouping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eDDm.png)
- [expected results: rows grouped by subcategory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GZMP.png) (this is what I want to get)
- [current incorrect results after my code runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUFqg.png)

[Documentation of the SpreadsheetApp.Group class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/group)

Comment: I believe it is referring to [`getRowGroup`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrowgrouprowindex,-groupdepth) instead of `getRowGroupAt`

Comment: thank you! yes it is!!

Comment: What is the criteria to use to determine which rows should be the "master" rows under which the "daughter" rows should be be grouped and collapsed? Is it something like "column A is blank, and the row is followed by at least one row where column A is not blank"?

Comment: So you just want to collapse all row groups in your range, or you also want to create them? Please consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet, clearly indicating the current situation and the desired outcome.

Comment: Filed bug in Issue Tracker to replace mentions of non-existent `getRowGroupAt`: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/189810246.

Comment: Issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/189810246 was fixed and the mentions of `getRowGroupAt` have been replaced by `getRowGroup` at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/group.

Answer (score 1):

You can most concisely group the rows in a single range like this:

`rangeStaff.shiftRowGroupDepth(1).collapseGroups();`

But it appears that you want to group and collapse *several* groups of rows, where the value in column `A` determines whether a row should be collapsed. In mother rows, column `A` is blank, and in daughter rows, it is non-blank.

Try a `groupRowsByCriteria_()` function like this:

```
function groupRowsStaffInWork() {
  const groupRowsBy = 'staffInWork!A2:A';
  groupRowsByCriteria_({
    keyRange: SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(groupRowsBy),
    motherRow: /^()$/i, // () means blank
    daughterRow: /^(.+)$/i, // (.+) means at least one character
    collapse: true,
  });
}

/**
* Groups all rows that meet criteria and optionally collapses the groups.
*
* @param {Object} criteria An object with this structure:
*                 {Range} keyRange The range within sheet where to find motherRows and daughterRows.
*                 {RegExp} motherRow A regular expression that identifies a value in the criteria column as a mother row.
*                 {RegExp} daughterRow A regular expression that identifies a value in the criteria column as a daughter row.
*                 {Boolean} collapse Optional. Whether to collapse the groups.
* @return {Sheet} The sheet where rows were grouped.
*/
function groupRowsByCriteria_(criteria) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 1 June 2021
  const sheet = criteria.keyRange.getSheet();
  const rowStart = criteria.keyRange.getRow();
  const rowEnd = getLastRow_(sheet);
  const keys = criteria.keyRange.getDisplayValues().flat();
  const daughterRows = [];
  keys.forEach((key, index) => {
    if (rowStart + index <= rowEnd && key.match(criteria.daughterRow) && !key.match(criteria.motherRow)) {
      daughterRows.push(rowStart + index);
    }
  });
  const runLengths = getRunLengths_(daughterRows);
  runLengths.forEach(tuple => {
    const [start, numRows] = tuple;
    const range = sheet.getRange(start, 1, numRows);
    range.shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
    if (criteria.collapse) {
      range.collapseGroups();
    }
  });
  return sheet;
}


/**
* Counts consecutive numbers in an array and returns a 2D array that
* lists the first number of each run and the number of items in each run.
*
* The numbers array [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 5, 4] will get
* the result [[1, 3], [5, 1], [8, 2], [11, 3], [5, 1], [4, 1]].
*
* For best results, sort the numbers array like this:
* const runLengths = getRunLengths_(numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b));
* Note that duplicate values in numbers will give duplicates in result.
*
* @param {Number[]} numbers The numbers to group into runs.
* @return {Number[][]} The numbers grouped into runs, or [] if the array is empty.
*/
function getRunLengths_(numbers) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 31 May 2021
  if (!numbers.length) {
    return [];
  }
  return numbers.reduce((accumulator, value, index) => {
    if (!index || value !== 1 + numbers[index - 1]) {
      accumulator.push([value]);
    }
    const lastIndex = accumulator.length - 1;
    accumulator[lastIndex][1] = (accumulator[lastIndex][1] || 0) + 1;
    return accumulator;
  }, []);
}


/**
* Gets the position of the last row that has visible content in a column of the sheet.
* When column is undefined, returns the last row that has visible content in any column.
*
* @param {Sheet} sheet A sheet in a spreadsheet.
* @param {Number} columnNumber Optional. The 1-indexed position of a column in the sheet.
* @return {Number} The 1-indexed row number of the last row that has visible content.
*/
function getLastRow_(sheet, columnNumber) {
  // version 1.5, written by --Hyde, 4 April 2021
  const values = (
    columnNumber
      ? sheet.getRange(1, columnNumber, sheet.getLastRow() || 1, 1)
      : sheet.getDataRange()
  ).getDisplayValues();
  let row = values.length - 1;
  while (row && !values[row].join('')) row--;
  return row + 1;
}
```